# How to enable upload file (default server configuration is disabled) in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I wish I upload a file from PhpStorm in my host, but `Tools -> Deployment -> default server configuration` is disabled.

My PhpStorm version is 10.0,
Before the question, I have read this page:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/uploading-and-downloading-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, for you specific request you need to set up a *default* server configuration.

Your current account does not have an associated remote server, so you can either goto `File > settings > deployment >` and Setup a server n this screen, or if you've already got a server, then you can select that server on this screen and click the "Make default" icon above the server list.

Alternatively you don't need a *default* server and instead use `Tools > deployment > Upload to...` and select one of your predefined servers associated with this account.

*The underlaying point here is that you need to tell PhpStorm your server details (from the deployment menu mentioned above) before it can connect to your server.*

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, I create setup a server (File -> setting -> deployment) and click "Make default" icon above the server list. but i can not upload any file from PhpStorm...

Comment: `Tools -> deployment -> upload to` is desabled

Comment: You may have to clear/invalidate caches if the server settings do not auto update to the account. You can do this from the `file` menu and then PhpStorm will apply the default server settings .